# How do I split a markdown file into separate files at the heading

Tags: markdown

I have a book in markdown format. I want to split it into separate files at the chapter headings. How can I do this?

Comment: So far I've used pandoc to convert a docx file into a markdown file. I've not tried anything else. I usually use php but I would imagine that trying to use regex to match the chapter headings isn't the most reliable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> have a book in markdown format. I want to split it into separate files at the chapter headings. How can I do this?

If you are using [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/), you can convert your Markdown file to EPUB, unzip the EPUB file and convert the HTML files into Markdown.
Not the perfect solution but you can accomplish it with a few lines of bash script like

```
pandoc -f markdown -t epub -o my-book.epub my-book.md
unzip my-book.epub
for chapter in *.html
do
pandoc -f html -t markdown -o ${chapter/html/md} ${chapter}
done
```

**You need to fix the path to the HTML files.**

If you want to program something and you have some experience, shouldn't be hard to write a Python/... script to split the file.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon a straightforward solution. Credit goes Christian Tietze and mediapathic!

```
`gcsplit --prefix='novelname' --suffix-format='%03d.md'  novel-file.md /##/ "{*}"`
```

https://christiantietze.de/posts/2019/12/markdown-split-by-chapter/

Other options:

https://github.com/marceljs/markdown-split

https://github.com/accraze/split-md

Answer (score 2):

I needed that exact functionality and was not content with the solutions provided in the other answers mostly because heading tags *within code blocks* were not respected which lead to problems with my documents.

So I went ahead and wrote a small [*python* tool named mdsplit](https://github.com/markusstraub/mdsplit) to do the job.
Install it via pip (`pip install mdsplit`) and then run this to e.g. split at level 2 headings:

```
mdsplit input.md --max-level 2
```

Only later I found out there is already a [*C++* based tool named mdsplit](https://github.com/alandefreitas/mdsplit) as well that does about the same:

```
mdsplit -i input.md -l 2
```